# Custom WinForm with MessageBox Icon and Sound

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, messagebox

I want to create a modal dialog that has more controls than what a standard .NET `MessageBox` offers you. I've created my own Windows Form that will be called with ShowDialog() to give the modal behavior. However, I'd like to utilize the graphics that come with MessageBox via `MesageBoxIcon`. Is this possible? Is it also possible to replicate playing the error/warning windows sounds associated with the message box icons (as they are set in the user's windows settings)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See `System.Drawing.SystemIcons` class to display the system icons the `MessageBox` class uses, such as `Question`, `Information` and `Warning`.

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(SystemIcons.Question.ToBitmap(), new Point(0, 0));
```

For the sounds, see the `System.Media.SystemSounds` class to play the associated sounds.

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that this was a nice reference for drawing the system icon:
http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=154680

Comment: You need to use Graphics.DrawIcon(), or some variation, as SystemIcons returns Icon, not Image, but you're essentially there.

Comment: @StealthRabbi Oops.  Updated code.  Yes, `DrawIcon` or use the `ToBitmap()` function.

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox is provided by the OS I'm afraid. You can extend it, but it requires a lot of work (see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19865/How-to-extend-the-native-MessageBox-dialog-in-NET) CodeProject article for a tutorial). Your best bet is probably to start again with a control inheriting from Form as you suggest.

To access the icons, it's as simple as using the `System.Drawing.SystemIcons` class (documentation for that is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons.aspx).)